# Adding a field to a structure without breaking existing code

Tags: c++, c, struct, codebase

So I'm working with this huge repository of code and have realized that one of the structs lack an important field. I looked at the code (which uses the struct) as closely as I could and concluded that adding an extra field isn't going to break it.

Any ideas on where I could've screwed up?

**Also:** design advice is welcome - what's the best way I can accomplish this?

**E.g.** (if I wasn't clear):

```
typedef struct foo
{
  int a;
  int b;
}
foo;
```

Now it's :

```
typedef struct foo
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
}
foo;
```

Comment: Add the real code.  You may have missed something.

Comment: As I said this is a **huge** repository of code which I can't post. All I'm asking for is tips on design and what I could've missed.

Comment: how is the struct used? Do you have byte boundaries?

Comment: Not that I know of - I have not seen any attempt to align data - is there anything else I should look for?

Comment: Of course it is going to break. There is __ABSOLUTELY__ no way you can tell if it will still work unless that structure is only used in 5 or less files. In which case re-compiling them would not be an issue. Get off your ass change the field and re-compile everything.

Comment: So you added this field, recompiled everything, ran it and it crashed? Or you're just double checking that it shouldn't break anything?

Comment: why do you think you screwed up?

Comment: Woah, ease up people, **it works perfectly** - I'm just double checking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you've written above I can't see anything wrong.  Two things I can think of:

1. Whenever you change code and recompile you introduce the ability to find "hidden" bugs.  That is, uninitialized pointers which your new data structure could be just big enough to be corrupted.
2. Are you making sure you initialize `c` before it gets used?

Follow Up:

Since you haven't found the error yet I'd stop looking at your struct.  Someone once wrote look for horses first, zebras second.  That is, the error is probably not an exotic one.  How much coverage do you have in your unit tests?  I'm assuming this is legacy code which almost invariably means 0% or at least that's been my experience.  Is this accurate?

Comment: Lol, there was a point where it was initialized, I forgot that - this will most probably be accepted :)

Comment: Then don't mark me as the answer.  If it's stil not working we can keep brainstorming.  That's what this site is supposed to be about, no?

Comment: Well, no that's the whole point, it works perfectly. I'm just trying to anticipate any problems. And since the existing code does not depend on alignment, the initialization was the only issue I had overlooked.

Answer (score 7):

If that structure is being serialized/deserialized anywhere, be sure to pay attention to that section of the code.

Double check areas of the code where memory is being allocated.

Comment: That's a great idea - luckily no serialization at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using sizeof(struct) to allocate memory at all places and are accessing the members using -> or . operators, I don't think you should face any problem. But, it also depends on where you are trying to add the member, it might screw up your structure alignment if you are not careful.

Comment: Struct alignment, thanks! I'm looking for something along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas on where I could've screwed up?

Nothing. Everything. It all depends on how, where and why this is used.

Assuming this structure you talk about is a C-style POD and the code is but the simplest, you'll get away with it. But, the moment you are trying something more ambitious, you are dealing with alignment issues (depending on how and where you create objects) and padding at least. If this is C++ and your POD contains custom operators/ctors etc -- you're getting into a lot of trouble. Cross-platform issues may arise, if you rely on the endianness ever etc.

Answer (score 2):

If the code had a robust set of unit tests, it would probably be much easier to track down the problem (you asked for design advice ;) )

I assume you don't need to use the new 'c' variable everywhere in this giant codebase, you're just adding it so you can use it in some code you're adding or modifying?  Instead of adding c to foo, you could make a new struct, bar, which contains a foo object and c.  Then use bar where it's needed.

As for the actual bug, it could be anything with so little information to go on, but if I had to guess, I'd say someone used a magic number instead of sizeof() somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Look for `memcpy, memset, memcmp`.  These functions are not member-wise.  If they were used using the previous structure length, you may have problems.

Also search the files for every instance of the `struct`.  There may be functions or methods that do not use the new important field.  As others have said, if you find the structure in a `#define` or `typedef`, you'll have to search those too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question C++:

For the future, [Pimpl](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom)/[d-Pointer](http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++#Using_a_d-Pointer) is a strategy that allows you much greater freedom in extending or re-designing your classes without breaking compatibility.

For example, if you had originally written

```
// foo.h
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(const Foo &);
    ~Foo();
    int a() const;
    void a(int);
    int b() const;
    void b(int);
private:
    class FooPrivate *const d;
};

// foo.c
class FooPrivate {
public:
    FooPrivate() : a(0), b(0) {}
    FooPrivate(const FooPrivate &o) : a(o.a), b(o.b) {}
    int a;
    int b;
};
Foo::Foo() : d(new FooPrivate()) {}
Foo::Foo(const Foo &o) : d(new FooPrivate(*o->d)) {}
Foo::~Foo() { delete d; }
int Foo::a() const { return d->a; }
void Foo::a(int a) { d->a = a; }
// ...
```

you can easily extend this to

```
// foo.h
class Foo {
public:
    // ...
    int a() const;
    void a(int);
    int b() const;
    void b(int);
    int c() const;
    void c(int);
    // ...
};

// foo.c
class FooPrivate {
    // ...
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
// ...
```

without breaking any existing (compiled!) code using `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is used to transfer data across the network, you could be breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

If adding a structure member anywhere other than as the first member breaks anything, then the code has undefined behaviour and it's wrong.  So at least you have someone else (or your earlier self) to blame for the breakage.  But yes, undefined behaviour includes "happens to do what we'd like it to do", so as the other guys say, watch out for memory allocation, serialization (network and file IO).

As an aside, I always cringe when I see typedef FOO ... struct FOO, as if one is trying to make C code look like C++.  I realize I'm in a minority here :)

Comment: And it's equally pointless to `typedef struct FOO ... FOO` in C++, where `struct FOO` already makes `FOO` available without the `struct` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Its always safe to add new elements at the end of a C struct. Event if that struct is passed to different processes. The code which has been recompiled will see the new struct member and the code which hasn't been will just be aware of the old struct size and just read the old members its knows about.
The caveat here is that new member has to be added at the end of the structure and not in the middle.